# Windows 10 takes too long at logo and spinning dots on boot

Tags: windows-10, boot

On hard reboots, that is, restarting the PC or unplugging it, Windows takes around 4-5 minutes to fully boot. The part that takes the longest is the logo + spinning dots. 
[image: Logo and spinning dots]

The dots spin for maybe 4 minutes until I finally get to the log in screen. This is very tedious and shouldn't happen on a SSD.

The PC boots in mere seconds if I enable fast startup.

Things I have tried already:

- Disabling fast startup
- Checking for viruses
- Performing a clean boot
- Updating drivers
- Updating Windows
- Uninstalling NVIDIA drivers
- Disabling Intel Management Engine Interface
- Unplugging all unnecessary USB/external devices

My specifications:

- Intel i7 6700k @ 4.6Ghz
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070
- SanDisk SSD Plus 240GB (boot and OS)
- Seagate Barracuda 2TB 7200RPM (for data)
- Corsair Vengeance 2x8GB DDR4 2400Mhz
- Gigabyte Z170X Gaming 3

**I ran Windows Performance Recorder and I'm willing to share the boot trace.** You can download the corresponding ETL file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fy32MADVAIy3fklA_U76C3YROJOqillp/view) (Google Drive).

Comment: Why are you against enabling fast startup that is one of the best features of Windows 8+

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not against fast startup, if anything, I'm forced to use it now if I don't want to wait 4 to 5 minutes every time I boot up. However, I dread the time something asks me to restart my PC, because I know I'll be in for a 5 minute wait.

Comment: Well if fast startup is enabled restarting should not be a big deal.

Comment: @Ramhound restarting acts as a "hard boot", it doesn't take into account fast startup. When I either restart my PC or unplug it (with fast startup enabled), I get 4-5 minute boot times.